# Why a Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException if the invoked method is there?

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic, anonymous-types

I have the following code which creates a dynamic object that is assigned to the smtpClient variable.

```
public class TranferManager
{
    public void Tranfer(Account from, Account to, Money amount)
    {
        // Perform the required actions
        var smtpClient = New.SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.Send("info@bank.com", "from.Email", "Tranfer", "?");
        // In the previous line I get a Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
        // with the description = "'object' does not contain a definition for 'Send'"
    }
}

public static class New
{
    public static dynamic SmtpClient(params object[] parameters)
    {
        return typeof(SmtpClient).New(parameters);
    }
}

public static class CreationExtensions
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Func<object, dynamic>> builders =
        new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, dynamic>>();

    public static dynamic New(this Type type, params object[] parameters)
    {
        if(builders.ContainsKey(type))
            return builders[type](parameters);

        return Activator.CreateInstance(type, parameters);
    }

    public static void RegisterBuilder(this Type type, Func<object, dynamic> builder)
    {
        builders.Add(type, builder);
    }
}
```

To test it I am using the UT (below):

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void TranferTest()
    {
        typeof(SmtpClient).RegisterBuilder(p => 
            new
            {
                Send = new Action<string, string, string, string>(
                (from, to, subject, body) => { })
            }
        );

        var tm = new TranferManager();
        tm.Tranfer(new Account(), new Account(), new Money());
        // Assert
    }
```

When I, using the inmediate windows, ask for the smtpClient type I get:

```
smtpClient.GetType()
{<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.Action`4[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]}
```

And when I ask for its members I get:

```
smtpClient.GetType().GetMembers()
{System.Reflection.MemberInfo[7]}
    [0]: {System.Action`4[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String] get_Send()}
    [1]: {System.String ToString()}
    [2]: {Boolean Equals(System.Object)}
    [3]: {Int32 GetHashCode()}
    [4]: {System.Type GetType()}
    [5]: {Void .ctor(System.Action`4[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String])}
    [6]: {System.Action`4[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String] Send}
```

So, my question is: Why am I getting that exception?

Comment: uhmm... copying all your code in a Console Application (and the content of your test method in my "main" method) it does not throw any exception for me. I guess your TestMethod is in a different dll. Maybe there's an issue with the .NET version you're targeting in the dll or its references?

Comment: Same thing here. When I run your code (having provided suitable definitions of Account, Money, etc) I get no exception.  Can you provide a small program that *actually compiles, runs, and demonstrates the problem?*

Comment: You are right, copying the test code in a "Main()" method of a console application it works. Now, I can see the problem: the annonymous type (created in the test dll) is not visible out of its dll.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Anonymous types are internal, if you cross assembly boundaries `dynamic` can't resolve the property.

Rather than using an anonymous type, try using an actual type or an Expando Object.

Comment: Thanks, The reason is right and pin point, can you give any soln.

Comment: Changing the internals to be visible to another assembly it's also a nice solution for unit tests - http://cstruter.com/blog/278

Comment: Please vote for this feature in Visual Studio [UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/7062098-support-object-initializers-on-expandoobjects).

Answer (score 11):

In the AssemblyInfo.cs try to add following:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("NameSpace1.SubNameSpace1")]
```

where NamsSpace1 is your project name and SubNameSpace is namespace of your dynamic/anonym object