# What is the difference between my codes when I use 'dynamic' to use AsQueryable method?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamictype

At first,I do not use `dynamic`,I just use the code like this,and it works well.

```
  List<Student> result2 = StudentRepository.GetStudent(sex,age).ToList();
  IQueryable rows2 = result2.AsQueryable();
```

But when I change it to `dynamic`，it is wrong.

```
 dynamic result = GetPeopleData(sex,age);
 IQueryable rows = result.AsQueryable();
```

and I add a method like this,I build the project it show that List do not have the AsQueryable method.How to change it?

```
 private dynamic GetPeopleData(int sex, int age)
    {
        if(sex>30)
            return StudentRepository.GetStudent(sex,age).ToList();
        else
            return TeacherRepository.GetTeacher(sex, age).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to make it dynamic?

Comment: You are showing the `GetPeopleData` method, but you call the `GetStudentData`. Is it right?

Comment: Because I just  want to get the data,not matter it come from student or teacher,I just want to change them to IQueryable rows  and them export these rows.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object-in-c-sharp ?

Comment: Go read up on inheritance and polymorphism.  There is no reason why you should need to use `dynamic` here.  You should almost never need to use `dynamic`.  Also, what is the point of creating an `IQueryable` from a `List<T>`?  Calling `ToList()` on your repository eagerly fetches all records and loads them into memory; you lose any opportunity for query operators to execute on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`AsQueryable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507003) is an extension method and [those don't work on `dynamic`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5311465/41071).

Depending on what you want to do, there are several possible solutions:

1. Don't use `dynamic`. Instead, make `Student` and `Teacher` implement a common interface (say, `IPerson`) and use that:

   ```
   private IReadOnlyList<IPerson> GetPeopleData(int sex, int age)
   {
       if (sex > 30)
           return StudentRepository.GetStudent(sex, age).ToList();
       else
           return TeacherRepository.GetTeacher(sex, age).ToList();
   }

   …

   var result = GetPeopleData(sex, age);
   IQueryable<IPerson> rows = result2.AsQueryable();
   ```
2. Call `AsQueryable()` as a normal static method:

   ```
   dynamic result = GetPeopleData(sex, age);
   IQueryable rows = Queryable.AsQueryable(result);
   ```

BTW, checking whether sex is over 30 doesn't make any kind of sense to me. You should probably rethink that part of your design.

Comment: That possibly depends on what  `sex` means here. I would rather not ask for more details.

Comment: @WiktorZychla The only alternative I can think of certainly couldn't be used to reliably distinguish between students and teachers. :-)

Answer (score -2):

[It is similar to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678608/why-a-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinder-runtimebinderexception-if-the-invoked-metho)

As @jbtule said,Anonymous types are internal, if you cross assembly boundaries dynamic can't resolve the property.

Rather than using an anonymous type, try using an actual type or an Expando Object.

Comment: I don't believe this applies as OP did not show any usage of anonymous types... (assuming `GetTeacher` returns `List<Teacher>` similar to the other one).