# SQLKata - Where Clause

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlkata

I've been trying to use SqlKata for a little while now and I'm really confused on how to get a single and simple WHERE clause to work.

I've been doing it as so:

`var sistemas = DatabaseHelper.factory.Query("tblSistema").Where("id_fornecedor", fornc.id);` it returns me an XQuery and I have no idea on how to execute it. Note that appending First() and Get() at the end throws an exception.
`'sistemas.Get()' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'`

I simply want to `SELECT * FROM tblSistema WHERE id_fornecedor=1` for example

Comment: "Note that appending First() and Get() at the end throws an exception." which error?

Comment: 'sistemas.Get()' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'

Comment: This should really be part of the question, why don't you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55456664/edit) it?

Comment: After short googling I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6309165/9363973) SO answer relating to your exception. Is it possible that you are passing a dynamic object to another assembly, or something along that line?

Comment: If you hard code a 1 in there instead of `fornc.id` do you still get the exception?

Answer (score 1):

`First()` execute the `XQuery` and returns the first record only of type `dynamic` in your case, internally it applies `Limit(1)` under the hood.

```
var book = db.Query("Books").Where("Id", 1).First();
```

`Get()` execute the `XQuery` and returns a `List<dynamic>`

```
var books = db.Query("Books").Where("Lang", "en").Get();
```

check more on https://sqlkata.com/docs/execution/setup#queryfactory

Answer (score 1):

```
var sistemas = DB.Query("tblSistema").Select("*").Where("id_fornecedor", fornc.id);
```

You can also do:

```
var sistemas = DB.Query("tblSistema").Select("*").Where("id_fornecedor", "=", fornc.id);
```

The operator is optional. `=` is the default.

And if you want to do certain selects, you would do:

```
var sistemas = DB.Query("tblSistema").Select("tblSistema.id_fornecedor", "tblSistem.blahSelect").Where("id_fornecedor", "=", fornc.id);
```